# Collaborative multi-output Gaussian processes

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process

I had been reading this [paper](http://auai.org/uai2014/proceedings/individuals/159.pdf) of multi-output gaussian processes. It is part of the literature review for a paper that I am writing. I download the software and was surprised that they are not using signals that are depending outputs between them. As soon I modified the functions to be dependent the algorithms do not want to fit the signals. If someone can take a look at this paper or the code and give me a comment, I will appreciate. I don't want to reject the algorithm without knowing other opinions.

https://github.com/trungngv/cogp

Comment: Are you only interested in the paper and code you cite, or would you be interested in other techniques for multi-output Gaussian Process Regression?

Comment: I am interested in know how can be correctly implemented because the code in the GitHub does not do what the paper claim. The GitHub has non-related outputs and as soon you relate the outputs it fails. The math looks ok. If you can give me your opinion about the method I will appreciate that.

Comment: to a first look, the methodology looks fine, even if IMO overcomplicated (there are simpler approaches to multivariate Gaussian processes). To tell you more I need to see what you did, i. e., you should post or link both the code with independent outputs, which ran ok, and the code with non-independent outputs, and see exactly what you mean by "failure".

Comment: Yes there are, I had the code from Multi-Output GP from Alvarez and Lawrence(works great). However the promise of lower times is too much....In the code they implement:
fn1 = @(x) sin(x) + 1e-7;
fn2 = @(x) -sin(x) + 1e-7;
y1 = fn1(x) + sqrt(1e-4)*randn(N,1);
y2 = fn2(x) + sqrt(1e-4)*randn(N,1);
if you change to cos or sin(fn1) in the second function the method stop working. If the frequency is incfeazse it will not converge. I think that there is an error in the likelihood.